# DataTable not refresh information

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables plugin with a dynamic html table, first of all, I draw my table with an ajax call, for that I use something like this:

**EDIT:**

```
Draw funcion ajax success
     success: function (data) {
            var aRC = JSON.parse(data.d);
            var lines = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < aRC.length; i++) {
                var id = aRC[i].Id;
                var num = id;
                var rev = aRC[i].Campo;
                lines += '<tr id="P' + num + '" data-id="' + num + '">';
                lines += '<td>' + num + '</td>';
                lines += '<td id="P' + num + '-1">' + rev + '</td>';
                lines += '<td class="text-center">';
                lines += '   <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="' + num + '"></span>';
                lines += '   <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="' + num + '"></span>';
                lines += ' </td>';
                lines += '</tr>';
            }
            $('#TableTBodyTag').html(lines);
            $('#TableId').dataTable({
                aLengthMenu: [
                    [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
                    [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
                ],
                "bDestroy": true,
                iDisplayLength: 10,
            });
        }
    });
```

Update Function ajax success

```
success: function (data) {   correctamente
        bootbox.alert(data.d);
        window.Fam.reset();
        Draw(); //Above function
    }
```

When I execute my update function everything it's fine, but my datatable is not refreshed I can't see the change until I reload the page (F5). I call `Draw function` on document ready and in my update function.

I can't change the way of table is created, so how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using a timer to call the ajax function?  And then getting the result and just wanting to update the datatable?  I presume you want https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload() or https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnReloadAjax

Comment: I'm using a function, I call this functions on documente ready and after my updateFunction submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did when I was using DT, modified to use your vars:

```
success: function (data) {   correctamente
    bootbox.alert(data.d);
    window.Fam.reset();
    $('#TableId').dataTable().fnDestroy();
    $('#TableTBodyTag').html("");
    Draw(); //Above function
}
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Ahhhahaha I see now. Totally unclear at first. Yes, I've dealt with this problem before for hours... I know how you feel! My Suggestion, which I think is the best for your sanity, is as my edited answer.

Comment: You save my life jajaja, thank you so much! This works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Ive been down this road myself. After some hard lessons I learned not to fight DataTables by trying to build and modify the html table manually.

That approach is doomed to failure in a myriad of ways.

Instead, use the ajax option to specify a data source and use [columns.render()](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) to create your html when the datatable is rendered.

When you make changes, update the remote data source then call `table.ajax.reload()` to rebuild the table.

```
var dataTableOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    "ajax": {
        "type": 'POST',
        "url": "/tools/somePage.php",
        "data": function(d) {
            d.command = 'getObjectInfo';
        }
    },
    columns: [{
        "orderDataType": "dom-text",
        "type": 'string',
        "width": '20%',
        "render": function(data, type, row) {
            // build all your html for the column here

        }
    }, {
        "orderDataType": "dom-text",
        "type": 'string',
        "render": function(data, type, row) {}
    }, {
        "orderDataType": "dom-text",
        "type": 'string',
        "render": function(data, type, row) {}
    }, {
        "orderDataType": "dom-text",
        "type": 'string',
        "render": function(data, type, row) {}
    } ],
    "tabIndex": -1

}


var table = $('#tableId').DataTable(dataTableOptions); 


table.ajax.reload()
```